# Laravel eloquent field calculation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

The following code output error like 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)+60' column doesn't exist.

How do I write it in eloquent style?

```
$affected_num = \App\TmpSetting
      ::where('name', 'last_schedule')
      ->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)+60')
      ->update(['value', 'NOW()']);
```

This code works, but $affected_num is an empty array.

```
$table = env("DB_PREFIX"). "tmp_setting";
    $affected_num = \DB::select(
      \DB::raw(
        "
          UPDATE 
            $table
          SET 
            value = NOW() 
          WHERE  
            name = :var AND 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)+60)
        " 
      ), array(
        'var' => 'last_schedule',
      ));
```

Comment: The first one is now in eloquent style.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to use whereRaw

```
whereRaw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)+60')
```

So we have

```
$affected_num = \App\TmpSetting
      ::where('name', 'last_schedule')
      ->whereRaw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)+60')
      ->update(['value', DB::raw('NOW()')]);
```